# SOAP Response Error: INvalid API key

Tags: xml, api, soap, wsdl, echosign

API Response for the send_document call for the Echosign.

HTTPI POST request to secure.echosign.com (net_http)
    SOAP response (status 500)
    
    
      
        
          soap:Server
          Invalid API Key:

```
API key is not the invalid one as this is working fine for the "getUsersInAccount" API call.

Did anyone faced this issue and know what could be the probable solution for this.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an data error. That means APi key which u are passing in request is not valid for particular operation. If you want to find the exact error, which is being return by server about that data, run this wsdl in soapui.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen even when the right key is used.

This happens when you pass the API parameters hash and add API key not at the first place, just need to make sure it always has the same sequence as mentioned in the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your API key has the right scope:
**getUsersInAccount** requires "user_read:account" 
**sendDocument** requires "agreement_send"

You can find out more in [here](https://secure.echosign.com/public/docs/EchoSignDocumentService21#sendDocument).